# Memory Error (OOM) while testing Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

I trained faster_rcnn_nas model with my custom dataset (resized images 1280x1080). My GPU is Nvidia Quadro P5000 and I can test the model on this computer.
When I test with GTX 1060 it crashes and gives memory error. But when I test pre-trained faster_rcnn_nas it works fine.

What is the differences between pre-trained and custom model?
Is there any way to run the model with 1060? Or is there any batch_size or similar parameters to change for testing?

What I have done: I limited my gpu and found out that I need minimum 8gb gpu to test my model.

Full error:

ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[500,4032,17,17] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node MaxPool2D/MaxPool-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

[[SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Sum/_275]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

(1) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[500,4032,17,17] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node MaxPool2D/MaxPool-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Answer (score 1):

For your **Question 1**: What are the differences between pre-trained and custom models?

This differs whether you will **train** the model or only use the model for **inference**.
 
Hence, when you use the **model for inference** it will require **very small memory compared to when training the model.**
But when you **train** the model using **Tensorflow GPU** this requires **more memory** **compared to CPU-only training but** with **faster execution time** especially when dealing with **complex model architectures** (ie. Faster RCNN),.

This is also noticeable when the model is using **computation heavy layers** like **Convolutional Layers**, as the speed-up of the calculations will be more **drastic** for the cost of **more memory**.

**Question 2:** Is there any way to run the model with 1060? Or is there any batch_size or similar parameters to change for testing?

When testing or inference, **data_length** is typically **arbitrary**, you could check this when the `input_shape = (None, ##,##)` the first parameter is `None`. This means that the model will accept data with any different length `lowest data_length = 1`.

Meaning you can only make use of **batch_size** when explicitly defined in the input shape `ie. (None, BATCH_SIZE, ##, ##)` or feed the model with **data with length of batch_size** `ie. (BATCH_SIZE, ##, ##)`.

One way to avoid Memory Error is to change the `batch_size` **parameter** of **model.predict** and **model.train** to a lower value, this will also increase your model **accuracy** but will **train longer**.

Another one is to convert your dataset into **Dataset Generator** which **caches** your data rather than loading it **directly into your memory**.

You could read more about **Building Input Pipelines in Tensorflow** on this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

Comment: Actually I have time prediction and training I need high accuracy as much as possible, for this reason I trained faster_rcnn_nas.
I see, I tried to find "model.predict" in object detection files to lower batch_size for prediction but couldn't find it. Is it a file or a parameter?

Comment: Hi @EmreTatbak, I would suggest that you open a new Question with your sample reproducible code that will allow us also to troubleshoot the problem.